# LibGDX ShapeRenderer Exception every time I run

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx

I'm working on remaking a game I made several years ago. It was originally made in Swing/AWT, and I was going to remake it in JavaFX, but decided to use a more powerful library instead, and opted to use LibGDX.

My current obstacle is drawing simple primitive shapes. In Swing or JavaFX, this is trivial. You just have a Graphics2D / GraphicsContext object and call drawing methods on them. But in LibGDX, I need to use a separate rendering object for primitives, because SpriteBatch can only draw textures.

So I'm trying to draw a basic rotated rectangle in my Particle class to represent a projectile.

```
@Override
public void render(SpriteBatch batch, ShapeRenderer sr, long cTime) {
    if(image != null) {
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(image, 
                   (float)(position.x - (image.getWidth() / 2)), 
                   (float)(position.y - (image.getHeight() / 2)), 
                   0.0f, 0.0f, 
                   (float)image.getWidth(), (float)image.getHeight(), 
                   1.0f, 1.0f, (float)(Math.toDegrees(theta + (Math.PI / 2))), 
                   0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), 
                   false, true);
        batch.end();
    } else {
        double x = position.x - (size.x / 2);
        double y = position.y - (size.y / 2);

        sr.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
        sr.setColor(color);
        sr.rotate(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, (float)(Math.toDegrees(theta + (Math.PI / 2))));
        sr.rect((float)x, (float)y, 
                size.x.floatValue(), size.y.floatValue());
        sr.end();
    }
}
```

This render is called from the player's render function, which is called by the ApplicationAdapter class' render method.

```
@Override
public void render(SpriteBatch batch, ShapeRenderer sr, long cTime) {
    getCurrentWeapon().render(batch, sr, cTime);
    if(img != null) {
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(img, 
                   (float)(position.x - (img.getWidth() / 2)), 
                   (float)(position.y - (img.getHeight() / 2)), 
                   (img.getWidth() / 2), (img.getHeight() / 2), 
                   img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), 
                   1.0f, 1.0f, (float)getDoubleAttribute("theta"), 
                   0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), 
                   false, true);
        batch.end();
    } else {
        sr.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
        sr.setColor(Color.RED);
        sr.circle(position.x.floatValue(), position.y.floatValue(), 40.0f);
        sr.end();
    }
}
```

And the main render method:

```
@Override
public void render () {
    update();

    long cTime = TimeUtils.millis();

    camera.update();
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    sr.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Begin drawing here.
    player.render(batch, sr, cTime);
}
```

And here is where I instantiate the SpriteBatch and ShapeRenderer.

```
@Override
public void create () {
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(Globals.WIDTH, Globals.HEIGHT);
    camera.setToOrtho(true, Globals.WIDTH, Globals.HEIGHT);

    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    sr = new ShapeRenderer();

    player = new Player();

    Cursor customCursor = Gdx.graphics.newCursor(new Pixmap(Gdx.files.internal("images/GZS_Crosshair.png")), 16, 16);
    Gdx.graphics.setCursor(customCursor);

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
}
```

The SpriteBatch and ShapeRenderer objects both exist in the ApplicationAdapter class and are passed to the various render methods to be used throughout all of its rendering calls.

But when I attempt to fire a projectile, I am immediately met with this exception:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no uniform with name 'u_projModelView' in shader
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShaderProgram.fetchUniformLocation(ShaderProgram.java:308)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShaderProgram.fetchUniformLocation(ShaderProgram.java:298)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShaderProgram.setUniformMatrix(ShaderProgram.java:528)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShaderProgram.setUniformMatrix(ShaderProgram.java:519)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ImmediateModeRenderer20.flush(ImmediateModeRenderer20.java:147)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ImmediateModeRenderer20.end(ImmediateModeRenderer20.java:160)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer.end(ShapeRenderer.java:1197)
    at gzs.game.gfx.particles.Particle.render(Particle.java:105)
    at gzs.game.objects.weapons.Pistol.render(Pistol.java:90)
    at gzs.entities.Player.render(Player.java:170)
    at gzs.game.GZS_Game.render(GZS_Game.java:65)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:225)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:126)
```

I have absolutely no idea what this exception means, and the very few results on Google don't have anything useful. What does it mean that there is no uniform of that name in the shader? I'm not using any shaders.

Did I create the ShapeRenderer wrong? It's instantiated in the ApplicationAdapter class' create() method, right alongside the SpriteBatch object.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `no uniform with name 'u_projModelView' in shader` shall be pretty clear. Your shader has no uniform such as `u_projModelView` (or is being optimized out because unused)

Comment: That tells me literally nothing. This is my first time using LibGDX and I have no idea what a uniform is or what u_projModelView is referring to. In every example I can find of using ShapeRenderer, there is no mention of uniforms or that one in particular.

Comment: Can you show your code for instantiating the ShapeRenderer? By the way, if your game has more than a few dozen objects to draw, you'll probably need to change your drawing approach for performance reasons. Store references to all your no-image objects in one array and the rest in another so you can draw all the SpriteBatch stuff in one batch (one call to end()), and likewise for the ShapeRenderer.

Comment: I've added the create() method where my SpriteBatch and ShapeRenderer are instantiated. Would it be possible to just begin both the SpriteBatch and ShapeRenderer before all my drawing calls and end them at the end of the render function? Or would there be conflicts from having both in their "begin" state at the same time? If it helps, I could commit the code I have now to Github and add a link to the entire game repo.